# Convert Html file to pdf in specific colour

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

```
options = {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'custom-header' : [
        ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    ]

}

pdfkit.from_file('htmlfile.html', 'tjprofile.pdf', options=options)
```

I want to change the html file to pdf with specific colour, how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

use BeautifulSoup to convert HTML to pdf

```
  import sys
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from PDFWriter import PDFWriter

def usage():
sys.stderr.write("Usage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " html_file pdf_file\n")
sys.stderr.write("which will extract only the text from html_file and\n")
sys.stderr.write("write it to pdf_file\n")

def main():

# Create some HTML for testing conversion of its text to PDF.
html_doc = """
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Test file for HTMLTextToPDF
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    This is text within the body element but outside any paragraph.
    <p>
    This is a paragraph of text. Hey there, how do you do?
    The quick red fox jumped over the slow blue cow.
    </p>
    <p>
    This is another paragraph of text.
    Don't mind what it contains.
    What is mind? Not matter.
    What is matter? Never mind.
    </p>
    This is also text within the body element but not within any paragraph.
    </body>
</html>
"""

pw = PDFWriter("HTMLTextTo.pdf")
pw.setFont("Courier", 10)
pw.setHeader("Conversion of HTML text to PDF")
pw.setFooter("Generated by xtopdf: http://slid.es/vasudevram/xtopdf")

# Use method chaining this time.
for line in BeautifulSoup(html_doc).get_text().split("\n"):
    pw.writeLine(line)
pw.savePage()
pw.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: @Parveen I want to convert from file not from string

Comment: rather than using the HTML code, use open function to open and read your HTML file, and store that value in the variable, and call that variable in the place of html_doc.

Comment: PDFWriter is not available for ubuntu users